# multi level menu programming output issue

Tags: php, menu, multi-level

I'm trying to make a multi level menu in php, but I can't output the html correctly.

Firstly I extract the data from db sort it after 'sort_id' and 'id' and store it in to an array.

DB structure:

```
id | parent_id | sort_id | title
---------------------------------
1  |     0     |    0    | test1
2  |     1     |    1    | test2
3  |     1     |    0    | test3
4  |     0     |    1    | test4
5  |     2     |    0    | test5
```

PHP code

```
function hasChildren( $id, $data ) {
  foreach  ($data as $d ) {
    if ( $d['parent_id'] == $id ) {
        return true;
        break;
    }
  }
}

function menu ($arr) {
  foreach ( $arr as $d ) {
    if( is_array($d) && $d['parent_id'] == 0 ) {
        echo "<li><a href={$d['link']}>{$d['title']}</a>";
        if ( hasChildren ($d['id'], $arr) ) echo "<ul>";
    }

    foreach ( $arr as $row ) {
       if ( is_array($row) ) {

            if( $row['parent_id'] == $d['id'] ) {
                if ( hasChildren ($row['id'], $arr) ) {
                    echo "<li><a href={$row['link']}>{$row['title']}</a><ul>";
                } else echo "<li><a href={$row['link']}>{$row['title']}</a>";

                menu($row);

                if ( hasChildren ($row['id'], $arr) ) {
                    echo "</ul></li>";
                } else echo "</li>";
            }
        }
    }
    if ( is_array($d) && $d['parent_id'] == '0' ) {
        if ( hasChildren ($d['id'], $arr) ) echo "</ul>";
        echo "</li>";
    }
  }
}
```

HTML output

```
<li>
   <a href="http://localhost">test1</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="http://localhost/2">test3</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://localhost/1">test2</a>
      <ul></ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/5">test5</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/4">test4</a></li>
```

after 'test2' is opening and closing an 'ul' tag

'test5' should be a child of 'test2' and not a parent

I know this might not be the best way to do it, but anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)   menu($row); is useless, because it does nothing

2)  if you want to apply recursion, you must write like this:

```
function menu($arr, $parent) {
    $open = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $row) {
        if ($parent == $row['parent_id']) {
            echo ($open?'':'<ul>')."<li><a href={$row['link']}>{$row['title']}</a>";
            menu($arr, $row['id']);
            echo "</li>";
            $open++;
        }
    }
    if ($open) {
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}

menu($array, 0);
```

Comment: oh my.. that was so damn easy.. I can't believe I wasted 2 days on thinking how to do it and was so simple and makes so much more sense.. Thank you very much

Comment: btw.. is **echo ($open?'':'<ul>')** instead of **echo ($open?'<ul>':'')**

Comment: it means 
`if ($open) {/* echo nothing */} else { echo '<ul>'; }`

Comment: i fixed it, please recheck

Answer (score 1):

If you can change your database table I would highly recommend storing your data using MPTT (modified preorder tree traversal). It solves a lot of problems** and this is a really good example: http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/

The CakePHP guys use MPTT combined with a parent_id field.

Assuming you can't or don't want to change your database, I would use PHP to preorder the data so that children are in the array after their parent and then output the menu. I started with some test code with uasort, but the logic quickly gets messy.

Accept the answer if you're going with MPTT or add a comment if you need some help with the second solution.

** - node depth, path to node, whole tree are easy to derive and code exists to do this already.

Comment: +1 and thank you very much. I'll look in to it since is new stuff for me. But for now @Alexandr answer is what I need

Comment: I agree. One thing to watch out for is that his solution is a O(n^2) solution. For just an app that has a small user population or data set that's not a big issue. If I were to use recursion, I'd use it to re-order the data with a merge sort, which is a O(log(n)) solution (or better yet use uasort, which allows you to focus on just the comparator). It's amazing the number of times I've seen "enterprise" level software with these sorts of O(n^2) solutions in them (on my last contract eliminating one of these sped up a web service call by 10,000%).